# How do I create a Deedle dataframe fom an SQL Server Table in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataframe, deedle

I am trying to populate a Deedle dataframe from an SQL Server instance I have on the cloud and have been having some trouble. I'm trying to easily load the table into a Deedle Dataframe. Right now I'm just able to print the table.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Deedle;
using DeedleCustomNamespace;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs = "Server=somedb.database.windows.net;Database=somedb;User Id=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword;";
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cs);

            try
            { myConnection.Open(); }
            catch (Exception e)
            { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1", myConnection);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myReader["Column1"].ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(myReader["Column2"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
            try
            { myConnection.Close(); }
            catch (Exception e)
            { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using to read data from the SQL server?

Comment: I'm using System.Data.SqlClient to access data on an SQL Server instance hosted on Azure. I added sample console code that demos what I can do currently. Ideally, I like to use a Deedle method to quickly populate a dataframe instead of adding row by row to a dataframe. @TomasPetricek

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs = "Server=somedb.database.windows.net;Database=somedb;User Id=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword;";
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cs);

            try
            { myConnection.Open(); }
            catch (Exception e)
            { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1", myConnection);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                var SomeDataframe = Frame.ReadReader(myReader);
                SomeDataframe.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
            try
            { myConnection.Close(); }
            catch (Exception e)
            { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
        }
    }
}
```